# How do I formulate the hypothesis when there is no given percentage?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I hope you are doing well.

I have been successfully solving hypothesis problems when I am given the percentage on the claim. However, now I have to solve problems with no given percentage. Have a look at these 2 examples.

Example 1:
the candy maker recently claimed that M&M’s were so much fun because they were a perfect rainbow, that is, each bag they made contained equal numbers of each of the five colors. The bag came with:

Brown: 19
Blue: 5
Green: 5
Orange: 9
Yellow: 10

Example 2:
Dr. Joseph claims that very young children are equally attracted to different colored balls. There are three balls to choose from, all identical in size.

How do I formulate the null hypothesis?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The *hope you are doing well* and *Thank you for your time* was probably unnecessary but it certainly made me feel good about myself - so thank you!

Comment: @learning123, I am completely respectful of people's time, effort and help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 48 M&M's in the bag and 5 colors, so one possible null hypothesis is that there are 9 Brown, 9 Blue, 9 Green, 9 Orange, and 9 Yellow in a typical bag. Or you could say the null hypothesis is that there are 10 Brown, Blue, Green, Orange, and Yellow M&M's in a bag. In terms of percentages, each color appears in 20% of the total M&M's in the bag is the null hypothesis. The alternative hypothesis is the actual percentage of M&M colors differs from a perfect 20%-20%-20%-20%-20% split.

For the children and balls, one null hypothesis could be that the proportion of children who pick color 1 is 1/3, color 2 is 1/3, and color 3 is 1/3. The alternative is that the population proportions differ from this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time explaining how you saw they hypothesis. On the example with the M&Ms, the 20% seems to be the best because the percentage allows me to obtain to the standard deviation.  And for the example 2 about the children, the 33.3% makes sense. I'll go with this. thank you for your time.